# Laravel Mysql statement like fcm topic condition

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, having-clause

I'm trying to make my own topics system similar to fcm on mysql.The table is simply this:

```
user_id  topic_name
```

In fcm for example:

```
'topic1' in topics && 'topic2' in topics or ('topic3' in topics)
```

means select the user, which is subscribed to topic1 and topic2 or is subscribed to topic3.

In mysql I have no idea how to do this,basically it's based on all equavelnt user_ids but on different conditions on topic_name but using whereIn and whereNotIn and stuff it's not possible I'm really confused.

Comment: in mysql  ( topics = 'topic1' AND topics = 'topic2') OR  topics = 'topic3'

Comment: @nbk topic1 and topic2 are saved in 2 rows, so that will not work.right?

Comment: No you can change it to OR or use   topics  IN ( 'topic1','topic2' , 'topic3' )

Comment: What do I do with and then?

Comment: o don'zthave an answer, because i don't know what you are exactly looking for. do thw quwry and ssee if yu get all rws needed

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select user_id
from mytable
where topic_name in ('topic1', 'topic2', 'topic3')
group by user_id
having count(*) = 3
```

This brings users that have the three topics listed in the `where` clause.

Comment: @stevemoretz: the having clause ensures that there are 3 rows in the group, while the where clause filters on the three topics your are interested in. Combined together, these ensure that the user has all all three topics.

Comment: Thank you but sadly this doesn't address all the problem.It was a bit more complicated than that.Basically :

\DB::select( "select distinct user_id from push_notification_topics as r where " . preg_replace( '/\'(.*?)\'.*?in topics/m', "user_id in (select user_id from push_notification_topics where r.user_id = user_id and topic_name = '$1')", preg_replace( '/\|\|/m', 'or', preg_replace( '/&&/m', 'and', $condition ) ) ) ) 

this is the answer I reached I had to select the table in the first select to cause it check for the stuff also all and and or works.With a little bit of regex